# Java8 Streams: filter out a map

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to figure out how to use Java8 streams for the following case:

Suppose I have the following Map:

```
Map<String,String[]> map = { { "01": {"H01","H02","H03"}, {"11": {"B11","B12","B13"}} };
```

And the desired output would be:

```
map = { {"01": {"H02"}, {"11": {"B11"}};
```

My attempt:

```
map.entrySet().stream() //
        .flatMap(entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.getValue()) //
        .filter(channel -> Channel.isValid(channel))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap()));
```

Comment: so you want the first all the time?

Comment: no, arbitrary one determined by the filter.

Comment: @Shvalb should the receiver type of the result set be `Map<String, String>`? or should it be `Map<String, List<String>>` for example?

Comment: @Aominè I'd say second, hard o solve this on the phone... :) plz u post an answer

Comment: Map<String,List<String>>

Comment: @Eugene tried, not sure if that's what the OP is trying to achieve though :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues with your current approach.

1. There is no [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) method with the signature `toMap()` so that will render a compilation error.
2. [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) expects a function taking a type `T` and returning a `Stream<R>` whereas you're attempting to pass a map as a return value so that will also render a compilation error.

Instead it seems like you want something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultSet = map.entrySet()
                .stream() //
                .flatMap(entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.getValue())
                        .filter(Channel::isValid)
                        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), e)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, 
                               Collectors.toList())));
```

or much simpler solution:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream() //
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
               a -> Arrays.stream(a.getValue())
                          .filter(Channel::isValid)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: hmm, I was really thinking into something related to `Collectors.filtering` as a downstream collector for `Collectors.groupingBy` here...

Comment: @Eugene but this post is tagged with java-8 :), although i'll work on a java-9 solution now.

Comment: @Eugene mhmm, just thinking about it. not sure if one can use `Collectors.filtering` here... but we can use `filter` in the valueMapper for sure

Comment: `Channel::isValid`? probably should just add a merge function for two keys... otherwise agreed.

Comment: @Eugene sure, I'll use a method reference but in this case, there should not be any key collisions as the source (a Map) by definition doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: @Eugene Right, I see :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way of solving your problem:

```
public static void stack2() {
    Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("01", new String[]{"H01", "H02", "H03"});
    map.put("11", new String[]{"B11", "B12", "B13"});

    Map<String, String[]> newMap = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .peek(e -> e.setValue(
                Arrays.stream(e.getValue())
                    .filter(Main::stack2Filter)
                    .toArray(String[]::new)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    newMap.forEach((key, value) -> 
            System.out.println("key: " + key + " value " + Arrays.toString(value)));
}

public static boolean stack2Filter(String entry) {
    return entry.equals("H02") || entry.equals("B11");
}
```